# Netbeans - Syntax Check error using php inside javascript

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting, syntax-error, netbeans-7

Netbeans 7.0 is highlighting lines as syntax error when i use PHP inside JavaScript

In my case

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rating_<?=$coObj->company_id?>").jRating({
        step: true,
        longStarsPath:"include/jrating/jquery/icons/btn_black_trans2.png",
        rateMax:1,
        phpPath:"include/jrating/php/jRating.php",
        <?php
        if($_SESSION["rate_of_".$coObj->company_id] == 1)
            echo 'isDisabled: true,';
        else
            echo 'isDisabled: false,';
        ?>
        type:'long',
        length : 1,
        decimalLength : 0,
        rateMax: 1,

        onSuccess : function(){
            alert('Success : your rating has been saved');
            location.reload(true);
        },
        onError : function(){
            alert('Error : please retry');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

all the lines below PHP code are highlighted, and first line says that **missing : after property id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your syntax to this:

```
isDisabled:<?php
    if($_SESSION["rate_of_".$coObj->company_id] == 1)
        echo 'true';
    else
        echo 'false';
    ?>,
```

Answer (score 3):

@Marek:
I don't really see that as an answer, more of a workaround (which doesn't always work)...

NetBeans should make things easier, not make us change syntax to avoid it failing in the highlighting...

Anyways, I use a lot of mixed Javascript/PHP code, and NetBeans fails miserably all over the place...I also use Notepad++ which doesn't have any problems with this...

Example:

```
function showUpload<?php echo $upload_number;?>(file) { /*some code*/ }
```

Or:

```
$('.option-help').qtip({
    content: function(api) { return $(this).parent().attr('data-tip'); },
<?php if ($option_help == 'icon') { ?>
    show: { event: 'click' },
<?php } ?>
    position: {my: 'bottom left',at: 'top left'}
});
```

Does anyone know of a better solution to the OP's question?!?